# What methods to recognize sentence handwriting?

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, image-recognition, handwriting-recognition

I mean posts per sentence, not per letter. Such a doctor's prescription handwriting which hard to read. Not just a normal handwriting.

In example :

> 1. I use a data mining or machine learning for doing a training from
>      paper handwrited.
> 2. User scanning a paper with hard to read writing.
> 3. The application doing an image processing.
> 4. And the output is some sentence from paper.

And what device to use? (Scanner or webcam)

I am newbie. If could i need some example in vb.net with emguCV/openCV and researches journals.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why i got a down vote for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow! The answer to your question is twofold:
a. If you want to recognize handwriting that has already happened i.e. it is presented to you as an image you are in trouble. Computer Vision is still not good enough to provide you with reasonable accuracy. 
b. If you have a chance to recognize handwriting “as it's happening” - you are in luck. Download, for example, a [Gesture Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.gesturesearch&hl=en) app from Android play store and you are in business.

The difference between the two scenarios is subtle but significant. In the second case you have an extra piece of information that makes handwriting recognition possible. This piece is timing of each stroke. In other words, instead of an image with handwriting you have a bunch of strokes that are all labeled with their time stamps. You can think about it as a sequence of lines and curves or as image segmentation - in any way this provides a big hint for the system. Additional help comes from the dictionary on your phone but this is typically used by any handwriting system.

Android of course has an open source library for [stroke recognition](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html) (find more on your own). If you still want to go for recognizing images though, you have to first detect text (e.g. as a bounding box) and second use any of the existing engines to process detected regions. For text detection I can recommend [MSER](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#mser). But be careful trying to implement even text detection on your own - you are entering a world of pain here ;). Here is an [article](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/149305/1509.pdf) that can help.

As for learning how to recognize text from images on the Internet - this can be your plan B or C or Z when you master above mentioned stages. Don’t try to abuse learning methods and make them do hard work for you - you will hit a wall if you don’t understand what’s going on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it is very difficult. How with using a database like this http://ijcaonline.org/volume27/number4/pxc3874475.pdf  (A Database for Amazigh Handwritten Character Recognition Research)

Comment: You typically don’t want to develop OCR (optical character recognition) on your own. People typically use either free ones or license them. You can still develop text a detection algorithm (finding binding boxes around each character) which will be fed to OCR.

Comment: Could we use an image recogniton? Is that different?

Comment: Good question. Image recognition is typically based on the assumption that objects are rigid. Characters are not. Objects to be recognized typically have more features than characters and rarely touch each other as in handwriting. This being said, people gave a thought to modeling non-rigid shapes. But the devil is in the details. I would stick to stroke transform and stroke analysis if I were you. However, if you are interested in other approaches, there is some interesting work on shape descriptors in log polar coordinates, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context